# how to add inside document library , announcement app in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-2013

In share-point we added document library app inside that we want to add 4 to 5 announcement app. Does any one know how to add app inside app...it will arrange app the things properly.

Comment: This question is unclear. Document libraries are a fundamental feature, not apps. You don't put other apps in them. Announcements are just a special list item type. Again, not something that goes into a document library - document libraries and lists are the two fundamental storage objects in SharePoint. Everything else is built on top of them

Comment: In any case this sounds like an end user question, not something related to SharePoint programming. You should probably post a question to sharepoint.stackexchange.com, but make sure the question is clear.

Comment: Then How can we arrange all announcement in share point?

Comment: That's even less clear - however you want. Move them to whatever zone you want, edit their settings. This is definitely *NOT* a programming question

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an end-user question about SharePoint usage. It may belong to sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: I want to combine multiple announcement together inside one folder or site its possible ?

Comment: If you can do it through the UI, you can do it through the API. A folder doesn't combine list items though, it organizes them. They're still independent items.

Comment: How to do with UI any blog/URL you have ?